# Problems appending objects to a list. Data is added correctly, but when verified it is not what I added

Tags: python

I need to fill a db with fake data. To do so I'm creating a list of objects. I generate 10 timestamps, and for each timestamp I create an object, add the timestamp and some randomly assigned data, then  it is appended to the list 5 times; each time given a unique id ('tag'). This format is quite specific as I am trying to simulate what the real data will be like.

Everytime I append a value, I run a print to show that the data is correct. Then when I am finished the entire operation, I print the entire list to double check. The first print value returns perfect. Yet the second tells me that I have 10 instances of identical data - my tag value is the same for 5 instances, then jumps up by 5, and repeat.

What am I missing?

```
cultures = [
    {
        'name': 'Pink Oyster',
        'scientific_name': 'Pleurotus djamor'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Brown Oyster',
        'scientific_name': 'Pleurotus ostreatus'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Blue Oyster',
        'scientific_name': 'Pleurotus Columbinus'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Chestnut',
        'scientific_name': 'Pholiota Adiposa'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Shiitake',
        'scientific_name': 'Lentinula edodes'
    },
    {
        'name': "Lion's Mane",
        'scientific_name': 'Hericium erinaceus'
    },
]

times = pd.date_range(start="2022-01-01",end="2022-07-20", periods=10).to_pydatetime().tolist()

data = []
count = 0
for time in times:
    raw = {}

    for key, value in cultures[randrange(0,5)].items():
        raw[key] = value
    raw['generation'] = randrange(0, 10)
    raw['stage'] = randrange(0, 3)
    raw['user_id'] = 1
    raw['created_at'] = time
    raw['updated_at'] = time

    for i in range(5):
        raw['tag'] = count
        count += 1
        
        data.append(raw) 
        #shows my data has been appended correctly
        print(data[-1])

#???????
print(data)
```

example first print - tag value increases by 1

```
{'name': 'Blue Oyster', 'scientific_name': 'Pleurotus Columbinus', 'generation': 5, 'stage': 1, 'user_id': 1, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'tag': 0}
{'name': 'Blue Oyster', 'scientific_name': 'Pleurotus Columbinus', 'generation': 5, 'stage': 1, 'user_id': 1, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'tag': 1}
{'name': 'Blue Oyster', 'scientific_name': 'Pleurotus Columbinus', 'generation': 5, 'stage': 1, 'user_id': 1, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'tag': 2}
{'name': 'Blue Oyster', 'scientific_name': 'Pleurotus Columbinus', 'generation': 5, 'stage': 1, 'user_id': 1, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'tag': 3}
{'name': 'Blue Oyster', 'scientific_name': 'Pleurotus Columbinus', 'generation': 5, 'stage': 1, 'user_id': 1, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'tag': 4}
```

example second print - tag is stuck at 4

```
[{'name': 'Blue Oyster', 'scientific_name': 'Pleurotus Columbinus', 'generation': 5, 'stage': 1, 'user_id': 1, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'tag': 4}, {'name': 'Blue Oyster', 'scientific_name': 'Pleurotus Columbinus', 'generation': 5, 'stage': 1, 'user_id': 1, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'tag': 4}, {'name': 'Blue Oyster', 'scientific_name': 'Pleurotus Columbinus', 'generation': 5, 'stage': 1, 'user_id': 1, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'tag': 4}, {'name': 'Blue Oyster', 'scientific_name': 'Pleurotus Columbinus', 'generation': 5, 'stage': 1, 'user_id': 1, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'tag': 4}, {'name': 'Blue Oyster', 'scientific_name': 'Pleurotus Columbinus', 'generation': 5, 'stage': 1, 'user_id': 1, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'tag': 4},
```

How am i changing the values of previous appends when I change the value after I append the data

Comment: You need to copy `raw`.

Comment: Why? I'm not saying you are wrong, I just want to know what is going on behind the scenes. What is python doing that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, stuff is passed around by *reference to value*. It basically means that primitive types (int, str, float) are passed by value, and complex types (list, object, dict) are passed by reference. So if you add `raw` to the list, you actually add the reference to it. You then change its contents, and add it again.

Instead of doing `data.append(raw)` try `data.append(raw.copy())`.

Comment: *Everything* is passed around as object references.  int/str/float are just immutable so you can't change them.

Answer (score 1):

You need a fresh copy of `raw` each time round the loop:

```py
for i in range(5):
    raw1 = raw.copy()
    raw1['tag'] = count
    count += 1
        
    data.append(raw1)
```

Comment: This works great....but why?

Comment: Firstly: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Secondly, `append()` does not make copies of its parameter.